# How to make CSS border on an image?

Tags: html, image, css, border

How can I crop an image (600х450) and create border on it using CSS?

[image: Original Image]

into

[image: Expected output]

Is it possible? What is better to use? Create some wrapper element with border-radius?

Comment: it is possible, using border-radius and css3 magic.

this link will start you on your way - http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/image-styling-coding-tutorials/

Comment: Something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/pLvvottd/)?

Comment: If you show some (investigation) effort you might even get some help. I would definitely also change the subject so it contains 'non-rectangle border'.

Comment: @Phylogenesis Here is the next step in your example: http://jsfiddle.net/pLvvottd/1/ I suggest that you add it as an answer, looks good.

Comment: I'm not convinced, if the OP is going to want something that looks closer to his example, then he is going to have to look into something like SVG.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the best you can do with css:

CSS:

```
img {
    width:400px;
    height:400px;
    border-top-left-radius:50% 50px;
    border-top-right-radius:50% 50px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:50%;
    border-bottom-right-radius:50%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/andyfurniss/rmc4nuu7/

Then just add a white border and a `box-shadow`.

Comment: *"Then just add a white border and a box-shadow"* - why not add it yourself to have a really good demo? Then you could embed it as stackoverflow snippet - then it would be even better.

Comment: Thank's for help, but it looks not very good (http://take.ms/ys1yU) And also my img is more precisely http://take.ms/B0I38

Comment: Yeah, I think you're always going to get a bit of a curve with `border-radius` which I understand is not quite what you need. I'm not sure you can do any better with pure CSS though.

Comment: @MaximDreddoff You're not going to be able to do what you want with pure CSS, then. If you want something closer to your example, then you will need to look into something like SVG - you can create much better masks using that.

Comment: @Phylogenesis you mean some kind of svg-animation?

Comment: @MaximDreddoff No. SVG isn't just for animations. It's a vectorised image format and allows you to do exactly what you want by creating a precise mask using lines, arcs, ellipses, Bezier curves and more.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/svg/default.asp

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
    #img{
        border-bottom-left-radius: 50%;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 50%;
        border-top-right-radius: 10%;
        border-top-right-radius: 10%;
        width: 600px;
        height: 450px;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: some explanation is usually appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I have update *@Phylogenesis*' [example](http://jsfiddle.net/pLvvottd/3/) to add borders, shadows and make it responsive.

In addition to not set fixed width and hieght, relevant portion of code is the following:

```
#mask img {
    margin-left: 50%;
    transform:translate(-50%, 0);
    border-bottom-left-radius:100%;
    border-bottom-right-radius:100%;
}
```